# AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser to System.collection.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm doing a hobby project for myself and later turn it into a portfolio work.
I'm working in Entityframework 6, with razor pages.

My class UserModel is a child of the IdentityUser class. (I presume you know what an IdentityUser, if not)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Inside the UserModel I also stores an Icollection of GroupClass.
My GroupClass has an ICollection of UserModels. Which creates a many to many relationship in EF6.

When i try to store the UserModel object in the groupclass, i get the error:   Cannot implicitly convert type to AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser to System.collection.Generic.ICollection.
What i understand is, i somehow need to change the class groupClass. To be able to store an identity variable instead of a Icollection usermodel. `
What i don't understand is, why isn't UserModel already a part of IdentityUser, as it's a child and should have the same parameters as it's parent.

My question is, how do i store the UserModel inside my groupclass?

```
public class GroupClassModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupClassID { get; set; }
        //   info dump removed
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserModel>? userModels { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class UserModel : IdentityUser
    {

  
         // info dump removed
 
        public int? groupClassID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GroupClassModel>? GroupClass{ get; set; }


     
    }
```

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              
                 //info removed
                if (newGroup == null)
                {
                    var NewGroup = new GroupClassModel()
                    {                     
                        userModels = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User)

                    };
                    Context.groupClass.Add(NewGroup );
                    Context.SaveChanges();

                }

                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
            return Page();
```

```
    public class Context : IdentityDbContext
    {
        Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
        {
        }    
        public DbSet<GroupClassModel> groupClassModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserModel> UserModels { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MasterModel> MasterModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
          
        }
    }
```

`

I tried changing the Icollection in both classes to Icollection. same problem. I tried changing Icollection To IdentityUser but i got tons of other errors. Now i'm 50/50 if latter is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupClassModel.userModels is a collection of UserModels. This line of code is trying to set that property to a single instance of a UserModel.

```
// this generates an error
userModels = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Instead you need to instantiate a new collection and add the current user's UserModel to that collection. (You're also going to need to cast the return value of userManager.GetUserAsync, which is an IdentityUser, to UserModel.)

```
userModels = new List<UserModel>();
// currentUser is an IdentityUser
var currentUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
// cast the IdentityUser to a UserModel
UserModel currentUserModel = (UserModel)currentUser;
userModels.Add(currentUserModel);
```

Comment: ah, i see, that's why i haven't been able to set multiple objects into my collection in previous work. 

But this works perfectly. Thank you @jefftrotman